# Example of noun described by adjective of the same root (like "homely home" or "reddish red")

Tags: adjective, derivation, word-play

In theory, we can easily attach a derived adjective to it's noun source. But, as far as I see this, it almost never happens. Yet, I would say, there are very few examples in some languages that are used in practice. Usually for emphasis - in order to stress the "pure"/essential/natural characteristics of the noun when they sometimes get blurred.

My question, out of curiosity: can we find such examples in the Latin corpus? **something like "coronaria corona" or "cibarius cibus"**? examples like the English "orange[color] orange[fruit]" also count.

Comment: The use of etymologically related words in a phrase (a "figura etymologica") is not terribly uncommon in New Testament Koine Greek — e.g. the shepherds in the Lucan nativity story εφοβηθησαν φοβον μεγαν. It appears that this is to some extent a Hebraicism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example from Ennius fragment 245 (from his tragedy *Iphigenia*, quoted in Aulus Gellius, *Noctes Atticae* 19.10.12):

> ***otioso** in **otio** <aeger> animus nescit quid velit.*
>
> In leisurely leisure a sick mind knows not what it wants.'

[Translation by E.H. Warmington]

Answer (score 3):

Also interesting example from Livy's *Ab Urbe Condita*, though it is not quite the same, but worth noting:

> Paucis ante diebus quam Syracusae caperentur, T. Otacilius cum quinqueremibus octoginta Uticam ab Lilybaeo transmisit, et, cum ante lucem portum intrasset, **onerarias frumento onustas** cepit; egressusque in terram depopulatus est aliquantum agri circa Uticam praedamque omnis generis retro ad navis egit.